# DataFrame histogram plot grouped and on the same figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a `DataFrame`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 3, size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
```

I want to split this into groups based on the last column and plot a histogram of all of the columns separated by groups in the same figure.

```
groups = df.groupby("D")
for type, group in groups:
    group.hist()
```

the code above will create as many figures as the number of groups and as many subplots as the number of columns. I would like to have all that in one big figure, without having to loop all over the columns of each group.